# I successfully added space to my Ubuntu partition, but now that I want to add MORE space, I can't

Tags: gparted, disk-usage, partitioning

I'm dual installed with Windows 10, tried out Ubuntu with only a few gigs, and now I want more.

Still a noob on this system. I read some threads and was able to shrink my C drive in windows a few gigs, and reassign it in Ubuntu using GParted.

When I tried to do it again to add even more space, it's not letting me "click and drag" my partition size at all. Saying the max size is 19999 MiB. (sda5)

Partition max size screenshot
[image: Partition max size screenshot]

I'm also unable to unmount the drives with the key next to them, I get an error, not sure if that matters.
Unable to unmount screenshot
[image]
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: sda5 appears to be a logical partition *within* extended partition sda3 - you'd need to extend that first

Comment: You have to use Ubuntu live installer which includes gparted or download a gparted ISO and create it as a live gparted/repair flash drive or DVD. You cannot unmount your working partition. And all partitions you want to edit must be unmounted. If you use Ubuntu live installer, it may also mount swap (and then all of extended), so swap off to unmount it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here.

First, you can't resize partitions while they're mounted, and since the partition you're trying to resize is your root partition, you can't unmount it while your Ubuntu installation is running. You'll have to boot from a live CD/USB and resize it from there.

The other problem is that the partition you're trying to resize is inside an extended partition which has no free space. You'll have to extend the extended partition first, then extend `sda5`.